# DRF with MongoDB getting the object data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF with MongoDB. I am inserting the JSON object in MongoDB in the external source.

This is my schema

```
_id : ObjectID("")
feed: Object
sensor_type: Int
received_at: datetime.now()
```

My question is how I can get this data using DRF using the serializer. I have one doubt is there any way I can this feed object?